# How to get StructType object out of a StructType in spark java?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on this spark java application and I wanted to access structtype object in a structtype object. For instance-

When we take schema of spark dataframe it looks something like this-

```
root
 |-- name: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- middlename: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- language: string (nullable = true)
 |-- fee: integer (nullable = true)
```

I wanted to grab the name as a structtype so that I can analyze it further. It would make a sort of chain. But the problem is that at the root level or any level, we can only extract structfield out of structtype and not other structtype.

```
StructType st = df.schema(); --> we get root level structtype
st.fields(); --> give us array of structfields but if I take name as a structfield i will lose all the fields inside it as 'name' is a StructType and I want to have it as it is.
StructType name = out of st  --> this is what I want to achieve.
```

Comment: Do you want the meta info like schema field or do you want to access the data values like "name" as a record on which you can do "name.firstname"?

Comment: @AzharKhan Meta-info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the parameters and methods mentioned in the [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.types.StructField.html):

```py
schema = StructType([StructField('name', StructType([StructField('firstname', StringType()), StructField('middlename', StringType()), StructField('lastname', StringType())])), StructField('language', StringType()), StructField('fee', IntegerType())])

for f in schema.fields:
  if (f.name == "name"):
    print(f.dataType)
    for f2 in f.dataType.fields:
      print(f2.name)

[Out]:
StructType([StructField('firstname', StringType(), True), StructField('middlename', StringType(), True), StructField('lastname', StringType(), True)])

firstname
middlename
lastname
```

Comment: Many thanks, That is exactly what i wanted. I missed the datatype method that it returns the child node/field as the child datatype.